# My span width expands to right but I want it to expand left and auto fit my content inside the span tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Please click the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtSK6.jpg
so that you understand I have marked the problem in red I want that time to automatically adjust width for example if the time is 1:25:34 then it expands to left and fill the content without overflowing. I hope you understood my css code which I have written is given below:

```
<span className="time">{props.time}</span> 
time{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8.4rem;
    left: 15.9rem;;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: fit-content;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
   
    width: fit-content;
    
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it seems like you forgot to put the image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too clear, but looking at your code it seems like you using a internal Css but it isn't in a style container
Make sure all CSS codes are placed into style then into head

Comment: Please check again I updated

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your container to be flexible, so as to fit into the box when it shows both the hours, minute and second, then you just add padding. This will create a gap between the text area and the borders.

Make sure to ignore width too as width is flexible

Hope this helps